# How to replace ï»¿ in string java

Tags: java, android, regex, xml

When i download xml from web,  `ï»¿`  appends to my xml.

How can i replace it from string. I know i can do it using

substring. but is there a **regex expression** to do this..

**Running code is**

```
XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();

xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(params[0]);

xml = xml.substring(3);
```

**XmLParse method**

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) 
    {       
        String xml = null;
        try 
        {
            //default http client
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            System.out.println("URL IN PARSER:==="+url+"====");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpentity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);   

            Log.d("response", xml);
        } 
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return xml;
    }
```

Comment: you can use ** replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)** this func

Comment: Sounds more like you're downloading it incorrectly

Comment: How do you download the file? Maybe it's worth to fix it already there.

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove BOM with regex, and not with a correctly set input encoding?

Comment: downlaoding is correct but i haven't display it using php.

Comment: tell me the way of using set input encoding @laalto

Comment: @laalto i have added my method to the question

Comment: Apache `commons-io` provides the `BOMInputStream` that could detect and/or remove the BOM.

Comment: Can we do it using Regex or not?

Comment: @Nepster [Pounding A Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)

Answer (score -1):

ï»¿ is the BOM in utf-8. Try this:

```
xml = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "utf-8");
```

Comment: So it's no xml after all, or maybe you are downloading an authenticated-user-only resource...so many possibilities. What does the html say?

Comment: yes i found out that I have to show xml using php and remove these with a function. I have directly uploaded an xml on server and trying to download it directly.